# C# Unable to consume message on Kafka topic?

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I've been looking through several examples of the Confluent.Kafka client (https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/), and whilst I can successfully get a producer to push a message into Kafka, I'm unable to pull any messages back down with consumers.

Through the UI I can see the topic is created and messages are going into this topic (there are currently 10 partitions and 3 messages), but my consumer always reports "end of partition", without any consumption of any message (the 3 remain on the topic and "OnMessage" never fires).

However the consumer is definitely accessing the topics, and can see 3 messages on one of the partitions:

*end of partition: dotnet-test-topic [6] @3*

It just doesn't consume the message and trigger OnMessage(). Any ideas?

```
var conf = new Dictionary<string, object> 
{ 
    { "group.id", Guid.NewGuid().ToString() },
    { "bootstrap.servers", "mykafkacluster:9094" },
    { "sasl.mechanisms", "SCRAM-SHA-256" },
    { "security.protocol", "SASL_SSL" },
    { "sasl.username", "myuser" },
    { "sasl.password", "mypass" }
};

using (var producer = new Producer<string, string>(conf, new StringSerializer(Encoding.UTF8), new StringSerializer(Encoding.UTF8)))
{
    producer.ProduceAsync("dotnet-test-topic", "some key", "some value")
            .ContinueWith(result => 
            {
                var msg = result.Result;
                if (msg.Error.Code != ErrorCode.NoError)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"failed to deliver message: {msg.Error.Reason}");
                }
                else 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"delivered to: {result.Result.TopicPartitionOffset}");
                }
            });

    producer.Flush(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
}

using (var consumer = new Consumer<string, string>(conf, new StringDeserializer(Encoding.UTF8), new StringDeserializer(Encoding.UTF8)))
{ 
    consumer.Subscribe("dotnet-test-topic");

    consumer.OnConsumeError += (_, err)
        => Console.WriteLine($"consume error: {err.Error.Reason}");

    consumer.OnMessage += (_, msg)
        => Console.WriteLine($"consumed: {msg.Value}");

    consumer.OnPartitionEOF += (_, tpo)
        => Console.WriteLine($"end of partition: {tpo}");

    while (true)
    {
        consumer.Poll(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the OnMessage event won't fire without the following config provided:

```
{ "auto.offset.reset", "smallest" }
```

With this added, I was able to read the messages on the topic.